# Migrating SOAP service from websphere to tomcat

Tags: java, soap, axis

I am trying to migrate the application which is running in websphere to tomee.

I am creating wsdl using axis, but one service is up but another is not working, it says

AXIS error

No service is available at this URL

what i did it:
right click on the service class->Web Service->Create Web Service ->Choosing Axis-> Next ->Start Server->finish

the same way it is working for one service but another service is not working.

Any help would be helpful.

Comment: can you post the full stack trace of error?

Comment: No error in the console or in the webpage, i supposed to get 
"Hi there, this is an AXIS service!
Perhaps there will be a form for invoking the service here..."
but i am getting "AXIS error
No service is available at this URL"

Comment: once the service up then only i can validate